# Replacing a single character in a dataframe?

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I've been looking all over Google for a solution.

I am pulling data using requests.get(), which outputs a lengthy block in JSON.

I've been able to normalize it and figure out how to put it into a PANDAS dataframe.

The problem I am having is taking the URLs in Columns X, Y, Z and removing the percent encoding. I'd be okay with removing it from the entire dataframe.

```
                                  stat.get.url
0                                                        
1                                                        
2                  entrance%7Cstate%2Fgoogle   
3                  entrance%7Cstate%2Fyahoo   
4                  entrance%7Cstate%2Fmsn
```

I've tried this code:

```
df.replace('%7C', '|', regex=True)
```

But that doesn't replace anything in the dataframe.

How can I replace the percent encoded characters and get them to be saved on the dataframe?

Comment: replace doesn't replace inplace, you need to assign it back to the object or use inplace = True

Comment: thank you so much i got this to work @Vaishali

Comment: Voting to close this as typo/can't be reproduced, since the issue was that the result wasn't being assigned to a variable.